# SQL - How to get rows for a unique object which are not processed even once for current date

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario, wherein I want to return the Zuora Object name from my log table of MSSQL 2016.
It should only return in result if it is not processed even once for the current date.

For example, Account object out of 3 runs was not processed in the first, processed in the second and then not processed in the third run then the query should not return Account in the result as it is processed at least once.

Similarly, if another object like Subscription has not yet been processed in all 3 runs it should print it.

I tried the below query but it is not giving me the expected result.

```
    Create table dbo.Zuora_JobStatus_test (
      Id bigint identity(1,1) not null,
      [Name] varchar(100),
      FileId varchar(100),
      recordCount bigint,
      processed bit,
      [status] varchar(100),
      [Timestamp] datetime
      )
    
    INSERT INTO dbo.Zuora_JobStatus_test ([Name], FileId, recordCount, processed, [status], [Timestamp])
    VALUES ('Subscription','FS1',10, 0, 'completed','2022-11-08 13:05:00.000'),
      ('Account','FA1',1000, 0, 'completed','2022-11-08 13:50:00.000'),
    ('Subscription','FS2',15, 0, 'completed','2022-11-08 15:05:00.000'),
      ('Account','FA2',1003, 1, 'completed','2022-11-08 15:10:00.000'),
        ('Account','FA3',1004, 0, 'completed','2022-11-08 16:10:00.000')
    
-- Below query prints input data
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Zuora_JobStatus_test ORDER BY NAME ASC, timestamp desc  
    

    -- Below query along with the Subscription also prints the Account row, which is not required as it was processed once for the current date.
    
     SELECT fileId, name, status, recordCount,[timestamp],processed
      FROM
       (
       SELECT  fileId, name, status, recordCount,[timestamp],processed,rn 
       FROM 
       (
         SELECT fileId, name, status, recordCount, [timestamp], processed 
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [TimeStamp] DESC) rn
         FROM dbo.Zuora_JobStatus_test
         WHERE [status] = 'Completed' AND [Name]  in ('Account','Subscription')
       ) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1 
       )x2
       WHERE x2.processed = 0
```

Using the above query I am still seeing Account in output which should not be the case as it is processed = 1 once for the current date in the second run.

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/AVUPHKte)

[image: Actual & Expected Output]

Comment: Why do you expect to have just ONE row in the result set (specifically `filed = FS2`)?  why not both `FS1 and FS2`? What's the logic behind it?

Comment: @GiovanniLuisotto fileId (FA3 & FS2) has nothing to do with my requirement. Still, FYI, they are always unique for each execution. Now, the reason I want only 1 row in the result is because as I mentioned in my post, I want rows in the result only for those objects which are not processed for the current date. So in this example, the Account is already processed (1) in the second run. so only subscription data is expected as it is not yet processed (0)

Comment: `fileId` has no part in the calculation by object (col `name`), but you want it in the output.
you state that: *if another object like Subscription has not yet been processed in all 3 runs it should print it.* well if I print it out you will get two rows, with `fileid` FS1 and FS2... but in your expected result you show only FS2... meaning some kind of logic HAS to be applied to it (only the latest row?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `not exists()` to check for exitance of the processed line

```
select *
from
(
       select *,
              rn = row_number() over (partition by [Name] order by TimeStamp desc, id desc) 
       from   dbo.Zuora_JobStatus_test t
       where  [status] = 'Completed' 
       and    [Name]  in ('Account','Subscription')
       and    not exists
              (
                 select *
                 from    dbo.Zuora_JobStatus_test x
                 where   x.[Name] = t.[Name]
                 and     x.processed = 1
              )
) d
where d.rn  = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick.
You just need to count/sum the number of successful processing by Object and date, then filter on that

```
SELECT 
    name,
    CAST([timestamp] AS date) AS ExecDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN processed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumOfSuccess
FROM dbo.Zuora_JobStatus_test
WHERE
    [status] = 'Completed' 
    AND [Name]  in ('Account','Subscription')
GROUP BY 
    name,
    CAST([timestamp] AS date)
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN processed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Giovanni Luisotto This is helpful. But still, it does not give me the expected result when I add fields which are needed (fileId, name, status, recordCount) which I have mentioned in my query. If I add these fields to your query then the output is changed and it again shows rows which are not processed in other executions.

Comment: I based my query on your current result set... provide a proper expected output and I'll look into it

Comment: I had shared https://dbfiddle.uk/AVUPHKte for query and actual output Still I have updated my post with an image showing Actual & Expected output. Hope this helps. Thanks.